# If two hypersurfaces are conformally related and one of them is a Cauchy surface, is the other a Cauchy surface too?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, causality, topology

I'm reading Wald's "General Relativity". In appendix D he states that conformal transformations preserve causal structure. Does this mean that they also preserve when a hypersurface is a Cauchy surface?

The reason I'm asking, is because I'm interested in determining if the FLRW spacetime is globally hyperbolic. A hypersurface of constant time in Minkowski spacetime (which is a Cauchy hypersurface) and a hypersurface of constant time in FLRW spacetime (with $k = 0$) are conformally related, meaning

\begin{equation}
\text{d} \Sigma^2_{\text{FLRW}} = a(t_0)^2 \text{d} \Sigma^2_{\mathbb{M}}
\end{equation}

where $a(t)$ is the scale factor. Does this imply that $\text{d} \Sigma^2_{\text{FLRW}}$ is a Cauchy hypersurface?

Intuitively speaking, this would make sense since FLRW spacetime is homogeneous and isotropic by construction, therefore we can foliate it by hypersurfaces of constant time with the condition that whichever two points in each of these hypersurfaces are isometrically related. Then, FLRW spacetime could be foliated with the hypersurfaces mentioned above, couldn't it?

Comment: The definition I had in mind is that a hypersurface is a Cauchy surface if its domain of dependence is the entire manifold (spacetime). However, I'm not sure if when conformally transforming a Cauchy surface it remains a Cauchy surface, because that depends on the spacetime it belongs to. Couldn't AdS spacetime be a counterexample?

Comment: Sorry -- I read the body of the question but didn't look closely enough at the title! I thought the question was supposing that the spacetimes were conformally related, not just that the hypersurfaces were conformally related like the title says. That makes my previous comment irrelevant, so I deleted it.